# 551 Error on output file

Tags: java, apache, groovy, ftp

I am using apache org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient to upload files to Apache FTPServer. When I call org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile, it always fail with "551 Error on output file" error.

This is my program

```
public class FileOperations {

   def ftp (params) {
         def ftp = new FTPClient()
         try {
            ftp.connect(params.host, params.port)
            println ftp.getReplyString()

            int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

            if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
               ftp.disconnect();
               System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
               return
            }

            boolean successLogin = ftp.login(params.username, params.password)
            println ftp.getReplyString()
            if(!successLogin) {
                println "FTP login unsuccessful "+params.username
                return
            }

            ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
            println ftp.getReplyString()
            ftp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE)
            println ftp.getReplyString()

            String absoluteFilename=params.file
            def isSuccessful = ftp.storeFile(params.file,new FileInputStream(absoluteFilename))

            println ftp.getReplyString()

            ftp.logout()

    } finally {
        if(ftp.isConnected())
            ftp.disconnect()
    }
}

   static main(args) {
     def operations = new FileOperations();
     def params = [:]
     params.put "host","localhost"
     params.put "port",2121
     params.put "username","test"
     params.put "password","test"
     params.put "file","C:/tmp/sample.txt"

     operations.ftp(params)
   }
}
```

## Output is

220 Service ready for new user.

230 User logged in, proceed.

200 Command TYPE okay.

200 Command MODE okay.

551 /C:/tmp/sample.txt: Error on output file.

I am not able to understand what this error means. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is

```
params.put "file","C:/tmp/sample.txt"
```

and you are using this as the *remote* filename, which should be an absolute or relative pathname, relative from the FTP user's FTP-side root directory, perhaps just "sample.txt". (There is no device such as `C:` on a FTP server.)

For reading the *local* filename, you'll have to use the full pathname, as you have it now:

```
String localFilename = "C:/tmp/sample.txt".
def isSuccessful = ftp.storeFile(params.file,new FileInputStream(localFilename))
```